# Can mixins access the state of the class they're mixed with in Dart?

Tags: oop, dart

Can mixins access the state of the class they're mixed with in Dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, through the use of `on` key word. This example illustrates:

```dart
void main() {
  final person = Bob();
  print(person.age);
  print(person.ageInside);
  // output will be 31, 13
}

mixin Comedian on Person {
  // no need to declare age variable here, it finds it through `on`
  @override
  int get ageInside {
    return age - 18;
  }
}

class Person {
  int age;
  int get ageInside {
    return age;
  }
  Person(this.age);
}

class Bob extends Person with Comedian {
  Bob() : super(31);
}
```