# How to write a mixin that can be added any number of classes, while having access to certain guaranteed variables?

Tags: dart

How to write a mixin that can be added any number of classes, while having access to certain guaranteed variables?

For example, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67842209/6622587) is okay, but what if wanted to the Comedian mixin to be available not just to the Person class, but to any class that has a `int age` variable?

Comment: link in question isn't working and I'm curious why you are posting question and answer in same minute... and this answer is suggesting basic lang component usage, something what every developer should know before posting questions on SO

Comment: I originally posted a noted with a link to https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/, which was edited out by @eyllanesc, who also changed my other article title, breaking the link.

Comment: @snachmsm 1) I have corrected the link, 2) In SO any user can answer any question (including their own), and you can answer it at any time. Many times users consider that they have found a problem that they have solved and that they want to share with the community, and I SO recommend that the question and answer be published at the same time.

Comment: @BenjaminLee I think what user snachmsm  points out is that what you point out is trivial that it does not deserve to be published, I do not think that he is criticizing the self-answer itself but that the question seems very basic

Comment: I think it passes the flow chart here: https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/should-general-reference-questions-be-asked-and-answered-here

Comment: Here's the top Google search results if you type my question into Google, including keyword Dart:
The first result (https://medium.com/flutter-community/https-medium-com-shubhamhackzz-dart-for-flutter-mixins-in-dart-f8bb10a3d341) covers overriding behavior but doesn't discuss state. The same is true with the second result (https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-what-are-mixins-3a72344011f3). The answer can be inferred from the docs (which are 3rd), but it takes a lot of sifting... In fact I'm not sure if it's answered anywhere there directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is through an interface. An interface is basically an abstract class that you use through the implements rather than extends keyword. While a class can extend only one parent class, it can implement any number of interfaces.

Here's a concrete example:

```dart
void main() {

  final person = Bob();
  print(person.age);
  print(person.ageInside);
//   output will be 31, 13
  
  final yogiBear = Yogi();
  print(yogiBear.age);
  print(yogiBear.ageInside);
//   output will be 40, 22
}

abstract class MortalCreature {
  int age;
  MortalCreature(this.age);
}

mixin Comedian on MortalCreature {
  // no need to declare age variable here, it finds it through `on`
  int get ageInside {
    return age - 18;
  }
}

class Person implements MortalCreature {
  int age;
  int get ageInside {
    return age;
  }
  Person(this.age);
}

class Bear implements MortalCreature {
  int age;
  Bear(this.age);
}

class Bob extends Person with Comedian {
  Bob() : super(31);
}

class Yogi extends Bear with Comedian {
  Yogi() : super(40);
}
```